# Issue in string matching in Python

Tags: python, string, file-io, special-characters

I am trying to read from a file and match for a certain combination of strings. PFB my program:

```
def negative_verbs_features(filename):

    # Open and read the file content
    file = open (filename, "r")
    text = file.read()
    file.close()

    # Create a list of negative verbs from the MPQA lexicon
    file_negative_mpqa = open("../data/PolarLexicons/negative_mpqa.txt", "r")
    negative_verbs = []
    for line in file_negative_mpqa:
        #print line,
        pos, word = line.split(",")
        #print line.split(",")      
        if pos == "verb":
            negative_verbs.append(word)
    return negative_verbs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print negative_verbs_features("../data/test.txt")
```

The file **negative_mpqa.txt** consists of *word, part-of-speech* tag pairs separated by a comma(,). Here's a snippet of the file:

```
abandoned,adj
abandonment,noun
abandon,verb
abasement,anypos
abase,verb
abash,verb
abate,verb
abdicate,verb
aberration,adj
aberration,noun
```

I would like create a list of all words in the file which has *verb* as it's part-of-speech. However, when I run my program and the list returned (**negative_verbs**) is always empty. The *if loop* wasn't executing. I tried printing word,pos pair by uncommenting the line *print line.split(",")* PFB a snippet of the ouput.

```
['wrongful', 'adj\r\n']
['wrongly', 'anypos\r\n']
['wrought', 'adj\r\n']
['wrought', 'noun\r\n']
['yawn', 'noun\r\n']
['yawn', 'verb\r\n']
['yelp', 'verb\r\n']
['zealot', 'noun\r\n']
['zealous', 'adj\r\n']
['zealously', 'anypos\r\n']
```

I understand my file may have some special characters like newline and return feed at the end of every line. I just want to ignore them and build my list. Kindly let me know how to proceed.

PS: I am newbie in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said the file has lines like this: `abandoned,adj` so those are `word, pos` pairs. But you wrote `pos, word = line.split(",")` which means that `pos == 'abandoned'` and `word == 'adj'` ... I think it's clear why the list will be empty now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line `pos, word = line.split(",")` by

```
word, pos = line.rstrip().split(",")
```

rstrip() removes the white characters (spaces, new lines, carriage return...) at the right of your string. Note that lstrip() and even strip() also exist. You also switched word and pos!

You could also use rstrip() on your word variable instead, when you append it to your list.

Comment: Vincent Savard, Thanks for the response. I did as you said but still no luck!

Comment: The output of print line.split(",")   is still ['wrought', 'adj\r\n']
['wrought', 'noun\r\n']
['yawn', 'noun\r\n']
['yawn', 'verb\r\n']
['yelp', 'verb\r\n']
['zealot', 'noun\r\n']
['zealous', 'adj\r\n']
['zealously', 'anypos\r\n']

Comment: I read too fast, my bad. In your code, the variable pos contains the word (i.e. yawn) and word, the type (i.e. verb). You have to switch them. I edited. Note that you still have to use strip() if you don't want to see those \r\n!

Comment: Vincent/Tony, Thanks. Just using what THC4k and rstrip() worked.